# .NET Core 2.2 WebAPI Route Conflict for Delete /Employees and /Employees/EmployeeID when parameter is null or empty

Tags: .net-core, routes, asp.net-core-webapi, conflict, webapi

There are 2 WebAPI routes,in .NET core 2.2

1)[Delete]
  /Employees

2) [Delete]
   /Employees/{EmpID}

When EmpID is null or empty instead of 2nd route first route is triggering.
I need the 2nd route /Employees/{EmpID} to trigger when route is "/Employees/" and 1st route to trigger when /Employees is invoked.

But in .NET core webapi in bot cases "/Employees"  and "/Employees/" triggering the same route /Employees.

How is it possible to trigger 2nd route when "/Employees/" is invoked.How to resolve the conflict with and without /

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need the 2nd route /Employees/{EmpID} to trigger when route is "/Employees/" and 1st route to trigger when /Employees is invoked.

You could use [URL Rewriter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting?view=aspnetcore-3.0#url-rewrite) to rewrite the request path.Refer to my below demo where `EmpID` is `int` type.

1.Create Rules

```
public class RewriteRuleTest : IRule
{
    public void ApplyRule(RewriteContext context)
    {
        var request = context.HttpContext.Request;
        var path = request.Path.Value;

        if (path.ToLower() == "/employees/")
        {                
            context.HttpContext.Request.Path = "/employees/0";
        }
    }
}
```

2.Add the middleware in startup Configure

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {

        app.UseRewriter(new RewriteOptions().Add(new RewriteRuleTest()));

        app.UseMvc();

    }
```

3.Test action

```
[HttpDelete("/Employees/{EmpID}")]
public void DeleteOne(int empID)
{
    if (empID == 0)
    {
        //for the condition when empID is null or empty
    }
    else
    {
        //for the condition when empID is not null or empty
    }
}

[HttpDelete("/Employees")]
public void Delete()
{

}
```

Comment: This answer helped me

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use [Route("[action]")] attribute to map multiple routes to correct  API methods. Below link explains more details for GET and POST routes. 
http://www.binaryintellect.net/articles/9db02aa1-c193-421e-94d0-926e440ed297.aspx

You can try the same for your DELETE routes.